# Get all $_POST variables starting with certain text

Tags: php, post

I have an html form with a section that generates inputs with random names.

Each input name is generated with the text "book" at the beginning and random text at the end.

```
<input type="text" name="book_4552f" />
<input type="text" name="book_3507p" />
<input type="text" name="book_8031b" />
```

How do I use PHP to get all $_POST variables which start with the text "book"?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The following uses [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) to check that the POST string begins with book_

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'book_') === 0) {
        // value starts with book_
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if(preg_match('@^book_@', $key)) {
    $books[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: did not close if statment if(preg_match('@^book_@', $key))

Answer (score 1):

There are several possiblities

First: (split key)

```
    $result = array();
    foreach($_POST AS $k=>$v) {
        //Explode k (book_*) into an array with max 2 values
        $k_array = explode("_", $k, 2); 
        if(isset($k_array[0]) && $k_array[0] == "book") {
            $result[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
```

Or with preg_match like above, but there is also a good reason that you might want just the last part of k = for example book_8031b just the 8031b

```
$result = array();
foreach($_POST AS $k=>$v) {
    if(preg_match("/^book_(.*)$/", $k, $matches)) {
        $result[$matches[1]] = $v;
    }
}
```