# Check and see if $_POST contains a specific string PHP

Tags: php

Im currently trying to figure out how can you check and see if a $_POST['email'] contains a specific string using php.

I currently tried

```
}elseif(empty($_POST['email']) || !strpos('@gmail.com', $_POST['email'])) {
```

the output says that the strpos does not contain the ending, when it does. What am i currently doing wrong, or is there another way of doing this?

I only want people to be able to register with gmail, and not any other unknown email accounts for spam use.

Comment: you should use `strpos(..)===false` instead of `!strpos(..)` as it can also return 0 as an index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all $\_POST variables starting with certain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825001/get-all-post-variables-starting-with-certain-text).

Comment: @md_5 Check what I posted below. You're best using `preg_match()` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably best off using `preg_match` with the `\b` pattern match instead of `strpos`. Plus, `strpos` will match `GMAIL` should you not want uppercase letters, you would want to use `stripos` instead, that will match it as case-insensitive, *an FYI*.

Using `strpos` will match `gmail.comm` instead of the intended `gmail.com`, which I'm sure you don't want. Users could very well enter `email@gmail.comm` and still be considered valid, something else I'm sure you don't want, which will fail in either trying to mail back, or using an auto-responder.

- From the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php - Based on example #2

> "The \b in the pattern indicates a word boundary, so only the distinct
>    * word "web" is matched, and not a word partial like "webbing" or "cobweb"

This will not match @GMAIL.com or @GMAIL.comm but will match @gmail.com but **not** @gmail.comm

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$contains = "@gmail.com";

$email = $_POST['email'];

// or use (as outlined below)
// if(isset($_POST['email']) && preg_match("/\b(@gmail.com)\b/", $_POST['email']))

    if(isset($_POST['email']) && preg_match("/\b($contains)\b/",$email )) {
        echo 'yey! gmail!';
    } else {
        echo 'invalid input!';
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

---

You can also just do the following, replacing what you're presently using:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && preg_match("/\b(@gmail.com)\b/", $_POST['email']))
```

---

Comment: IMO, this is much better, anyway i hope when the OP goes back online, should consider picking this one.

Comment: Thanks @Fred -ii- for the help today, and me figuring out my errors and confusion today. Using preg_match since you went a little bit more further and precise way to do this, has saved me a lot of trouble of what have could've happened in the future.

Comment: and @Ghost since I could not add more than 1 additional user in 1 post :)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to try something else, instead of `strpos`, you can do this:

```
if (empty($_POST['email'] || array_pop(explode('@', $email)) != "gmail.com") {
    // Do something if the email is empty or the domain is not "gmail.com"
}
```