# How can I use WooCommerce hooks that have parameters along with other functions?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This hook has some parameters `$item_data, $cart_item`, that the hook `woocommerce_get_item_data` needs to have in order to work.

```
function display_cart_item_custom_meta_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
  $adults = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $cart_item['tmpost_data']['tmcp_select_0']);
  $children = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $cart_item['tmpost_data']['tmcp_select_1']);
  $infants = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $cart_item['tmpost_data']['tmcp_select_2']);
  $number = $adults + $children + $infants;
  $number = array_sum(str_split($number));
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_cart_item_custom_meta_data', 9, 2 );
```

What the above function does, is checking the cart for 3 custom values. These values are:

```
3 adults
2 children
1 infant
```

And the variable `$number` is being split so that we can remove the words and just keep the sum number, which in this example is `6`. Next, we need to register a text field to show at the Checkout page, like this:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
  $persons = $number;
  for ($i=1; $i <= $persons; $i++){
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field' . $i . '"><h2>Person #' . $i . '</h2>';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name' . $i, array(
      'type'          => 'text',
      'class'         => array('my-field-class' . $i . ' form-row-wide'),
      'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
      'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
        'required'          => true
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' . $i ));
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
```

The above function is simply registering a text field that the client has to fill. This field is the name of each passenger. But the total number of fields registered needs to be the same as the first function (in our example `6`).

So using the `for` loop, we can run the registration for the text field `6` times, or in general `n` times depending on what the variable `$number`'s value is set.

The error that I get is a PHP Notice: `Notice: Undefined variable: number`.

Comment: `woocommerce_get_item_data` is **not performed once on the cart page but per cart item** (product). It's also **a filter hook, so these should always return a value**, something your code is missing. 
Maybe you should clarify your question, add where the custom value comes from? this because there may be another (better) solution than what you have applied so far

Comment: These custom values come from a plugin that adds custom fields inside the product page. The user simply states how many adults, children and infants are going to be in the trip. So i have to sum these people, get a value like 6 and then create in the checkout page 6 new fields that ask for each person's name. Then these 6 values needs to be also saved in the Order inside admin.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GNwg1Xpp - This is the code and it works if i manually set $number value to be 6 by hand. I just cannot get $number to be able to be read from another function.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have 3 custom fields on the single product page (adults children infants) and that values are loaded upon add to cart as $cart_item meta.

If that's already working like that, on the checkout page you simply need to loop over cart items, read $cart_item meta and see what's inside. If yes, you can then display your N fields.

I'd combine your two functions, without the need of using 'woocommerce_get_item_data'. I assume there can be more than one item in the cart, so I will be calculating the max value from $numbers. I also assume your $number code to calculate the total is working:

```
function bbloomer_custom_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {
  
  // loop over cart items and calc $numbers 
  $numbers = array();
  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
     if ( $cart_item['tmpost_data']['tmcp_select_0'] && $cart_item['tmpost_data']['tmcp_select_1'] && $cart_item['tmpost_data']['tmcp_select_2'] ) {
        $adults = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $cart_item['tmpost_data']['tmcp_select_0']);
        $children = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $cart_item['tmpost_data']['tmcp_select_1']);
        $infants = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $cart_item['tmpost_data']['tmcp_select_2']);
        $number = $adults + $children + $infants;
        $numbers[] = array_sum(str_split($number));
     }
  }
  $persons = max( $numbers );
  for ($i=1; $i <= $persons; $i++){
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field' . $i . '"><h2>Person #' . $i . '</h2>';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name' . $i, array(
      'type'          => 'text',
      'class'         => array('my-field-class' . $i . ' form-row-wide'),
      'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
      'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
        'required'          => true
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' . $i ));
    echo '</div>';
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'bbloomer_custom_checkout_fields' );
```

Comment: There is an error i get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'. If I remove the IF statement inside the foreach, the code works correctly. But the problem is also that i have more functions below that i didnt post here. One function validates these fields, the other one updates the post_meta, and the last one saves these field values inside the Order in Admin. So the $number variable needs to be also indide these functions too.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GNwg1Xpp Here is the full code. Because when i register these fields, I want the client to fill in the names of every passenger. And these values need to be stored inside admin. BTW i fixed the error before. There was missing a ] and a ) from the IF statement.

Comment: There is a missing comma after `if ( $cart_item['tmpost_data']`...., editing shortly

Comment: For example i need to do the validation in the hook `add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');` so i dont really know how to get the `$number` variable inside.

Comment: At that stage (validation) you don't need to know how big is $number, because you already get the $_POST value of "my_field_name1", "my_field_name2", etc. You can simply loop through $_POST and see which fields start with "my_field_name": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825001/get-all-post-variables-starting-with-certain-text

Comment: OK im trying this atm. Does the same also work for `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address` hook? In order to save the values in admin.

Comment: Yes I think you can use the same method. You avoid recalculating $number every time

Comment: The suggestion you proposed about $_POST worked correctly for the validation. But the problem comes on hook `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`. How can I do `update_post_meta` without writing the whole field `my_field_name_1` ?